# Do developers watch player match recordings for their online games?

Tags: game-mechanics, server, data, streaming, character-development

When developers plan and decide on new buffs and nerfs, do they gather information from online game matches, recorded secretly from their servers' data feeds and reconstructed / analyzed offline - for such data as player movement trajectories and popular paths, weapon preferences and gamestyle behaviour?

Comment: This is a yes/no question. Yes/no questions are not a good fit for our site, specially when asking what developers do, as there is not a single way developers handle things. What is the issue that you're facing in the development of your game?

Comment: Yes, in fact many studios work directly with popular streamers.

Comment: Can you think of any reason why they would *not* do this? Who's going to turn down free insights into how to improve their game/product?

Comment: @Jon I'm not sure this is about players/streamers, but more about internal recordings of games. /shrug

Comment: Honestly they employ a variety of techniques. Usually when looking into balance issues for simpler games (TF2 or Overwatch), they will track player statistics to see which characters are used and how well they perform (damage over time, healing, kills, etc). As you suggested they may even track player movements to generate heat maps for levels to see which paths are popular and where players often engage in combat.

Comment: Devs will also monitor social media to see which characters are popular or what mechanics are causing complaints. As far as videos go, they will obviously watch official tournament play since these events are normally endorsed by the companies themselves, but usually they will skip streamers. It's not that their insight isn't important, it's usually just because live streams can be a couple hours long, are padded out with uninteresting commentary/jokes, and yield very little data compared to other sources. Honestly they would get more information just by playing online themselves.